# Liferay structure template get Image name

Tags: image, templates, liferay, structure

I have image field in structure for Web Content display:

```
<root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US">
<dynamic-element dataType="image" fieldNamespace="wcm" indexType="keyword" name="image_1" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="wcm-image" width="">
    <meta-data locale="en_US">
        <entry name="label">
            <![CDATA[Image 1]]>
        </entry>
        <entry name="predefinedValue">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </entry>
        <entry name="tip">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </entry>
    </meta-data>
</dynamic-element>
```

and next template:

```
<#if image_1.getData()?has_content >
<div><img alt="Image 1" src="${image_1.getData()}" /></div></#if>
```

After I select and upload test.jpg image I only have image url like: localhost:8080/image/journal/article?img_id=10813&t=1431521227390. How can I save/get real image name (test.jpg) which was upload.

Answer (score 2):

The original name of image is not stored anywhere, so you can not get this name after uploading. The only information stored in image table are:

- imageid
- modifieddate
- type_
- height
- width
- size

Workaround might be changing type from image to documents and media, and selecting this image from portal. The URL of the document from the Document and Media library is being stored to the web content in the following format:

> /documents/[doc-group-id]/0/[doc-title]/[doc-uuid]

Here is part of code which let you get original title of document

```
<#assign doc>
  ${image_1.getData()?string}
</#assign>
```

Title : ${doc?string?split("/")[4]}

I think this is quite good idea since, you will be not storing multiple time same image used in different articles.

Comment: Hi tomic, thank you for your answer. If I'm correct: document from the Document and Media library saved in dlfileentry table in db and I can view such images using liferay Media Gallery. But if I upload image using Web Content Display it will not saved in dlfileentry, it will saved in journalarticleimage without title/name. Such image have not url like you describe (/documents/[doc-group-id]/0/[doc-title]/[doc-uuid]). That is a problem

Comment: @Arina I have updated my answer to point exactly how Liferay resolves type of image and document-and-media type. As I mentioned, personally i would suggest you to change your type to document-and-media type which has several advantages over image type.

Comment: Is there a way to get the description field?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I hided default file chooser. Displayed button which render click to file chooser and label which displayed text what I need.