# Image Description in Liferay Web Content Template

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, freemarker

In my web content structure, I have a Document and Media type field so that users can select an image. In the web content template, I want to get the selected image's description so that I can fill in the alt text for the image.

How do I go about doing getting the description information of that selected image in the template?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215536/liferay-structure-template-get-image-name

Comment: @ParkashKumar That unfortunately only helps with title but doesn't help get any of the other fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get fields like description, you need to first get the image ID. Then you'll use the DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil to get the file. Once you get the file, you can call the function to get the description.

```
<#assign imgID = Image.getData()?string?split("/")[5]?split("?")[0]>
<#assign fileEntry = staticUtil["com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil"]>
<#assign file=fileEntry.getFileEntryByUuidAndGroupId(imgID, groupId) >

${file.getDescription()}
```

You can get the other metadata of the document/image by calling one of the other functions for the [DLFileEntryModel](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/5.2/javadocs/portal-service/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/model/DLFileEntryModel.html).